# get client connection with accept() through non-blocking socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I am learning socket programming and I found some weird behavior when I test `accept()` function.

First of all, I made non-blocking server socket:

```cpp
int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
fcntl(server_socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

And then waiting for client connection after `bind()`, `listen()`.

```
while(1)
{
    errno = 0;
    new_socket = accept(server_socket, (sockaddr *)&new_address, &new_len);
    if (errno != EAGAIN)
    {
        printf("new_socket %d, connected\n", new_socket);
    } else {
        printf("no pending connection");
    }
    sleep(2);
    printf("finished one rotation\n");
}
```

Here is the problem. Since i am using non-blocking fd, it should detect pending connection with EAGAIN as written in [manual accept()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html).

> If the socket is marked nonblocking and no pending connections are
>   present on the queue, accept() fails with the error EAGAIN or
>   EWOULDBLOCK.

But when i tested with web browser (localhost:port), It shows two connection pended.

```
no pending connection
finished one rotation
no pending connection
finished one rotation
new_socket 6, connected
finished one rotation
new_socket 7, connected // accept() two connection of the same client
finished one rotation
no pending connection
^C
```

- Is it the basic browser behavior to try to connect two times ?
- How I can accept only one connection from client ??

Comment: You have it back to front. EAGAIN means *no* pending connection, and `new_socket >= 0` represents a new inbound connection. You've already been told about the rest of this. Duplicate.

Comment: What behaviour do you see in blocking mode?

Comment: @G.M. even blocking mode, it shows two connection.

Comment: @user207421 Oh I found reason. actually webrowser send one time for webpage and second for favicon

Comment: *You* found it? I told you that yesterday.